# How to arm APM using Mavproxy without overrinding rc channels

Tags: dronekit-python

I'm using the Dronekit-python API to control my APM-based drone and lately I've been facing a problem trying to arm it with the code `vehicle.armed = True` but I just get an error. I've also tried to arm it directly from Mavproxy using `arm throttle` and always gives the next MAVLik message: `COMMAND_ACK {command : 400, result : 3}`. That's the only way MAVLink have of returning a result, with a code. In this case 3 means "UNKNOWN/UNSUPPORTED" but it doesn't give more information like the cause of the error. And command 400 is because de order is arm/disarm.

After some trials tests I've managed to arm it if I previously overrive the third radio-control channel (the throttle channel) to some value other than 0 with `rc 3 1000`. The problem is that if I do that it disables that channel and I can't use that channel anymore unless I set it again to 0.

I've searched into the codes of other people and nobody seems to have the same problem. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get when setting vehicle.armed ?

Comment: I just get the message `COMMAND_ACK {command : 400, result : 3}`. Mavlink only give a result code, that in this case is 3 and means "UNKNOWN/UNSUPPORTED". It doesn't feedback me with more information of the error. Sorry.

Comment: I don't know if its necessary but the code 400 for the command is the one associated with the arm/disarm action.

Comment: What do you see when you run this example: http://python.dronekit.io/examples/vehicle_state.html ?Which drone are you using. 
It is also important to note that on copter you have to take off within 15 or so seconds of arming or the Copter will automatically disarm.

Comment: The battery I was using with the drone died a week ago, so at the moment I can't run that code. But I've done it when starting with the API and everything seemed right. I know that if you have the throttle at minimum for 15 seconds the drone disarm by himself. It gave me some troubles at the beginning, but this time it's not the problem.  The autopilot return an error when I'm trying to arm it, not after. Thank you.